# What fallacy is this that I see all the time?

Tags: fallacies

What is this fallacy? I see it all the time. Someone will say something like “it’s so good to see these animals released from captivity” and then another will reply with a response along the lines of... “so you care about animals in captivity but not about the millions of slaves in Africa” or something.

They reply like you can only care about one or the other and not both. But also, the initial comment is relevant to the context and so progresses the conversation while the response seems completely unrelated.